# Unity game flipped after deploying

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, arcamera

I havea game that uses ARCamera from Vuforia. When running in Unity the game works no problem. After I deploy the game to UWP, however, it seems that every thing has flipped. Almost as if I was looking at the game from the back. Even the writing is reversed. when deploying the game to android devices this does not happen. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you publishing to the hololens, per chance? Either way, try disabling MSAA on your camera.

Comment: Disabling MSAA did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ReflectionMode which flips the view horizonally.  This is used when using a front facing camera.

If you look at the 'Vuforia Core Samples Example' from the asset store, they have a CameraManager script that shows how to handle camera configuration.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. Thanks